# NAF Nodes, Automation with Robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I'm having a problem in accessing some components on my UI using Robotium. I discovered there are some nodes (NAF nodes) that are not accesible from automated tool as Robotium.

Is there a way to access them? I would not use click using specific coordinates.

Could you suggest me the best practices for problems like this?

This is the image of layout seen from UI Automator.

[image: UI Automator capture of screen]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the elements of a particular list view the following code should help you achieve that:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) solo.getView(id); //id is R.id.(list view id).
if (lv.getChildCount() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lv.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
    // Code to access each row of the list view. In my case each row is a linear layout and       has a text view.
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) Utils.getViewAtIndex(lv, i,
                    getInstrumentation());
        TextView accountName = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.(TextView id));
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is hardly coupled to layout; so if layout changes this code should be maintained. 
I'd like to identify a button using its id or contentDescription or other; but my problem is that I can't do that...

Comment: Yes I know. But if the layout could change then the id's could change too..that I think is true for whatever code we write with Robotium, its hard coupled to an extent. Do let me know if you find a better solution.

Comment: We agreed with our developing team not to change the Id of already declared components; so this problem has been partially resolved. 
I need a solution for this, and as soon as I'll be able to click button using their ids I'll let you know!