# Robotium - Trying to click home button in app

Tags: java, android, junit, robotium

I'm new to `robotium` and i'm trying to write a quick and dirty script to run through all screens in an app.

The problem i have  mainly with the 'home button' in the app. I've tried lots of options but i cant seem to get it to click there except with index, which is not what i want.

When i check out the button with the `hierarchyviewer` it looks like this:

[Link](http://postimg.org/image/qbsn9zy7n/)

However when i try for example:

```
assertTrue(
"Wait for text (id: myapp.R.id.home) failed.",
solo.waitForImageById("myapp.R.id.home", 20000));
solo.clickOnImage((ImageView) solo.findViewById("myapp.R.id.home"));            
solo.waitForActivity("MenuActivity");
```

It fails at the `waitForImageByID` line. Ive tried multiple options like `waitForImageButton` etc, but i just cant seem to get it clicked. What am i missing here?

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: View with id: '0' is not found!
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.getView(Solo.java:1990)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.getView(Solo.java:1970)
at com.bitbar.recorder.extensions.OtherUtils.a(OtherUtils.java:246)
at com.bitbar.recorder.extensions.OtherUtils.b(OtherUtils.java:241)
at com.bitbar.recorder.extensions.v.a(Waiter.java:71)
at com.bitbar.recorder.extensions.ExtSolo.waitForImageButtonById(ExtSolo.java:4176)
at com.example.android.apis.test.Test.testRecorded(Test.java:137)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1740)
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Do you have a android:contentDescription set for this image?

Comment: I have not developed this app my self, so the only information i have is what i can extract from the hierarchyviewer.

Comment: Ok! When you use hierarchyviewer do you see an exclamation mark in a triangle that indicates there are NAF nodes in your screen?
Give a look to this for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358149/naf-nodes-automation-with-robotium

Comment: Thanks for the help so far Flavio.

I have taken a look at it in uiautomator and i see the following: 

http://postimg.org/image/ks7bdnxzb/

So it looks like there are some descriptions on the linear layout actually. Do you know if i can click on this based on that?I did not see anything regarding NAF nodes.

Comment: Let's try to click using solo.clickOnView(" .... "); and insert as argument the label of content description. Let me know if it works.

I opened an issue about a similar problem here: https://code.google.com/p/robotium/issues/detail?id=560&colspec=ID%20Type%20Stars%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: Tried this but did not work, also tried a simple clickOnText for GPS-tracking, but even that did not work. That works fine for me in other parts of the app

Comment: What about with this: solo.clickOnView(solo.getString("myapp.R.id.home")); or solo.clickOnView(solo.getString("home"));

Comment: Getting android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0 
when i try those

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following line to press the home button in the action bar

```
solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton();
```

Comment: Does that not just simulate a press on the home button on the device? Im trying to click a view in the app wich contains an imageview with the id: home. Anyway i tried your solution but it did not get me any further

Comment: Ive uploaded another uiautomator image here: http://postimg.org/image/jq6a518vp/

Basically im trying to select the red outlined part. On the right you can see the hierarchy of the elements.

Comment: My first answer doesn't work on all OS versions. I updated it with one this better and simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the id that it is referring is not in your application, it is in androids default R file, try android.R.id.home and it should work fine. It is worth noting though that if your application uses action bar sherlock to support the action bar pre 4.0 that this will have a different ID there and you will have to handle this in your test.

You can see this for yourself looking at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html

Comment: Thanks alot for this comment, i totally overlooked this... Works fine now! CHeerS!

Comment: Could you upvote/accept my answer so people know this was the right answer in case they suffer the same issue!

Comment: Ive accepted your answer. I just noticed that now my test is running on my S4 with 4.4 android. But still does not work on older versions, this is because of action bar sherlock then? How can i see this?

Comment: If you look at hierarchy viewer on the older device you will see it is has a different ID. What i tend to do is create a class the encapsulates the functionality of the action bar and have two different implementations one for ABS one for native action bar. Then at run time of test i check the android version. However you can just try to find one and if it is null then try the other, will work just as well to start with!

Comment: Are you using TestDroid to record script?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using ActionBarSherlock there are two different Ids you have to check, android.R.id.home for API-Level>11 and abs__home for lower levels (provided by ActionBarSherlock):

```
    View homeButton = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.home);
    if (homeButton == null) {
        homeButton = activity.findViewById(R.id.abs__home);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this code:

```
ArrayList<LinearLayout> ll = solo.getCurrentViews(LinearLayout.class);
//You can change 1 with the ordinal number of LinearLayout you want to click.
solo.clickOnView(ll.get(1));
```

or also

```
ArrayList<ImageView> iv = solo.getCurrentViews(ImageView.class);
//You can change 0 with the ordinal number of Image you want to click.
solo.clickOnView(iv.get(0));
```

I think if you identify the correct id for view or linear layout or image view it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Dave C's answer was working only partially for me. The button was clicked but before the preceding screen was loaded assertions had started and thus were always false. The solution is to run "home click" on the main thread (Robotium 5.2.1):

```
getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I can see that it is an image view. You can click on any view using the following piece of code.

```
View view = solo.getView("View_name_from_hierachy_viewer");
solo.clickOnView(view);
```

View_name_from_hierachy_viewer in your case will be "home".
 Let me know if this does not work.