# Robotium Home Button and resuming to app

Tags: android, robotium

I'm new to Robotium testing and I want to test the following scenario:

1.) Start the app do something.
2.) Press the Home Button.(Close the app)
3.) Resume the app and test if everything is ok.

My question is how can I achieve steps 2 & 3 ?

Comment: by home you mean to close the app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661264/robotium-trying-to-click-home-button-in-app might help you.

Comment: Yes, By Home I mean to close the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with robotium, neither with pure Android Instrumentation framework. You should rather take a look on UIAutomator, if you have to test such scenarios.